# How do I parsing dates from Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to parse the schedule for my old high school's football team.

I've managed to get the node that contains the date for each game, but when I try to convert it to a Ruby date object I get an invalid date error. But, when I copy and paste the date that `puts gamedate` produces into the script for testing purposes, it converts to a date object just fine.

What is the difference between passing the string of `gamedate` to `strptime` and pasting it in as a hard coded input?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/fitzgerald-hurricanes-(fitzgerald,ga)/football/schedule.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
games = doc.css('.dual-contest')
games.each do |game|
  puts gamedate = game.css(".event-date").xpath('@title').to_s
  #works
  puts date = DateTime.strptime('2013-08-24T02:30:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  #does not work
  puts date = DateTime.strptime(gamedate,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end
```

Comment: I am getting the data...correctly.. which version ruby you are using?

Comment: Ruby Version 1.9.3p392

Comment: just to clarify when I copy and paste sample output from puts gamedate to string it works. However when i pass gamedate straight into the same function it fails.

Comment: what's the version of `nokogiri`?

Comment: When you ask a question, you need to include both the code, *AND* sample data, instead of pointing to a link that has data. As is, *WHEN* that link dies, your question will be mostly valueless. With the data, it will continue be useful. See http://sscce.org/ for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the reason:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/fitzgerald-hurricanes-(fitzgerald,ga)/football/schedule.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
games = doc.css('.dual-contest')
games.each do |game|
  puts gamedate = game.css(".event-date").xpath('@title').empty?
end

# >> true
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
# >> false
```

---

Look it another way,there is one table data,which has `nil` value:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/fitzgerald-hurricanes-(fitzgerald,ga)/football/schedule.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
games = doc.at_css('.dual-contest').at_css(".event-date").at_xpath('@title')
puts games
# ~> -:6:in `<main>': undefined method `at_xpath' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

---

I would go this way:-

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/fitzgerald-hurricanes-(fitzgerald,ga)/football/schedule.htm"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css('#schedule .event-date').each do |nd|
  dt = nd['title']
  p dt,DateTime.parse(dt)
end
# >> "2013-08-24T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-08-24T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456529j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-09-07T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-09-07T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456543j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-09-14T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-09-14T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456550j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-09-21T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-09-21T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456557j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-09-28T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-09-28T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456564j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-10-05T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-10-05T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456571j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-10-12T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-10-12T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456578j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-10-19T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-10-19T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456585j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-10-26T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-10-26T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456592j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# >> "2013-11-02T02:30:00"
# >> #<DateTime: 2013-11-02T02:30:00+00:00 ((2456599j,9000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: The `games` CSS query is also finding a `<div>` that seems differ from the table rows that the OP is processing. The fix is to improve the selectivity of that query.